# routing with just one of two parameters of controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

I have an actionresult with two parameter:

```
 public ActionResult Index(int a,string b)
        {
            //some code

            return View(b);
        }
```

it creates this url automatically:

```
  mysite.com/a=1&b=http://site.com/b=1
```

I just need to show first parameter "a" in my url:

```
  mysite.com/a=1
```

I use the default route of MVC that creates in global.ascx:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

what should i do?
Thanks...

Comment: What do you mean by it "creates this url automatically"? Also, are those supposed to be `mysite.com/?a=1`?

Comment: @parKing it means that this url is created automaticlly by using default route. i want to hidden b parameter from this url. can i do that?

Comment: Sorry, but I've never seen MVC "create" a URL. you should be able to hit that route with `mysite.com/?a=1`. Also, if you don't want `b`, why is it on the method? Does including it alter the functionality? If so, you could probably split them into two methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing the "b" parameter bleed through from the current request, you can set the "b" parameter explicitly to empty string to avoid this behavior:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { a = 1, b = "" }, null)
```

I [reported](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1346) this "feature" as a bug, but the developers at Microsoft seem to think this behavior is supposed to make your URLs easier to configure, and they don't intend to fix it.

> What you're seeing here is a feature of routing where "ambient" values (i.e. values that were detected in the incoming request's URL) are used to simplify (sometimes...) the generation of routes to other pages.
>
> You can check our my answer (under the name "Eilon") in this StackOverflow post, where I explain the behavior in a bit more detail:
>   [How Can I Stop ASP.Net MVC Html.ActionLink From Using Existing Route Values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817421/how-can-i-stop-asp-net-mvc-html-actionlink-from-using-existing-route-values)
>
> Ultimately if you want the most control over what gets generated for a URL there are a few options to consider:
>
> 1. Use named routes to ensure that only the route you want will get used to generate the URL (this is often a good practice, though it won't help in this particular scenario)
> 2. Specify all route parameters explicitly - even the values that you want to be empty. That is one way to solve this particular problem.
> 3. Instead of using Routing to generate the URLs, you can use Razor's ~/ syntax or call Url.Content("~/someurl") to ensure that no extra (or unexpected) processing will happen to the URL you're trying to generate.
>
> Thanks,
>   Eilon