# Html.ActionLink sends the rout engin the get params

Tags: asp.net-mvc

lets assume i have the following in my view

```
Html.ActionLink("ping", "X","Y");
```

and in the route class

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "X",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/OId/{o_id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

the out put of the action link while i'm on this page `X/Z` is

```
/X/Y
```

which is correct but if the request GET Params included a variable named o_id the output is

```
/x/y/OId/*
```

while i didnt send any params to the ActionLink Method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Can I Stop ASP.Net MVC Html.ActionLink From Using Existing Route Values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817421/how-can-i-stop-asp-net-mvc-html-actionlink-from-using-existing-route-values)

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Mr. @msmucker0527 i just dont want the action link to take any parameters i dont send.